# Kafka topics - How to ensure a one-key-one-partition relationship

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working on a project where I would like **to ensure I have 1 and only 1 key per partition** in my topic.

The problem is that I don't know the number of specific keys I will produce data from (could be 1, 2, or 1000 ! The number of different keys streamed vary in time).

In a topic, I know we have to specify an initial number of partitions, but we can add more after creation.

**What would be the best solution to ensure 1 key 1 partition?**.

*I have some leads...*

- I could create a topic with 3000 partition in advance so I have a buffer, but it is definitely not optimized. What about disk space consumption? What about the impact on performances?
- I could add partitions once I run out of available partitions, so I will only have the same number of partitions as keys, but there will be collision and it will threaten the continuity of the event stream as potentially a key will be assigned to a different partition
- I could override the default Partitioner used by my Producer services to ensure there is no collision between keys and the resizing does not affect, but how my consumer will know the partition the partitioner choose? How to ensure no other Producer affect the same partition number to another key...

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Why do you only want to have one key per partition? The purpose of the partitioner is to have a known mapping from any given key to a partition, so that downstream systems (specifically Kafka Streams or ksqlDB) know where to look for any given key, while not having to maintain more partitions than needed.

Comment: Overall, this sounds like a bad design as it appears you're going to want to lock in one consumer/client to one partition as well, which defeats the purposes of scalability and decoupling. What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve, and are you sure Kafka is the correct tool for this?

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! You are right I face bad design solution here... My use case is that I have MarketConnector services (producers) and other services (consumers). If Consumer-1 wants trades for btcusdt, and Consumer-2 wants trades for btceth, I don't want C1 to see btceth trades, and C2 btcusdt trades. I could have different topics, but it is also a bad design. Of course if a Consumer-3 wants also to see trades for btceth, it will consume the same data stream as C2. I want to avoid filtering at the consumer level, as they will fetch lot of useless data.

Comment: I have a similar issue, and the solution that has been implemented is one topic per client. This works, but means that adding a new client involves the administrative overhead of creating a new topic. If I was to implement this, I would consider putting the messages in a DB (needed in my case anyway because the client can request that they be resent) and have a single topic which contains just a notification to the client that there is new data, so that they don't have to poll the DB. The consumers would have to ignore the notifications for other clients.